# Определить день недели javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Есть формат 25.04.2015 23:10:00, нужно определить какой это день недели ПН ВТ и тд. Пробовал через getDay(), но на выходе NaN.

Comment: «Есть формат» — это что? Приведите код.

Comment: alert(["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"][new Date("25.04.2015 23:10:00").getDay()])

Comment: А дата у вас в порядке? http://jsfiddle.net/em5qku6j/ На моём FF выдаёт "Invalid date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dString = "25.04.2015 23:10:00";
var myDate = new Date( dString.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/,"$3/$2/$1") );
alert(["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"][myDate.getDay()])
```

Comment: Старайтесь не только давать готовый фрагмент кода, но и объяснять в ответе ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Через js такую дату невозможно обработать, Date() принимает дату либо в виде кол-ва миллисекунд либо через функцию Date.parse() в формате 2015-04-25 23:10:00

Comment: Ну, прямо уж невозможно. Вручную можно распарсить всё, что угодно.